# AVD in Android Studio 2.2.1 is showing blank black screen

Tags: android, emulation

I am new to Android and this is my first program, followed to the letter from the tutorial in android site. No build errors. On run the AVD is also coming up but nothing is showing. I read this forums and youtube but still couldn't figure out. The emulator comes up but it doesn't show anything. My program does only Hello world!

Kindly assist. There is no issues with the m/c I am running `Win 10, i7 - 2.9 ghz, 16GB ram`, just got it for the android work. I am using `Android studio 2.2.1`, minsdk (15) is lower than the target (24)

at one time I got this error but mostly no errors and emulator comes up empty.

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\Users\VSL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img: could not open disk image C:\Users\VSL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\VSL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\/system.img': Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the google api system images of the targeted api sdk installed or not.

If not install it from SDK Manager